# Using complex integration to count discrete points: is it plausible?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, contour-integration, integer-lattices

I recently come up with some wild ideas. Suppose we have a good enough (say, simple and smooth) closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $(x(t), y(t))$, and we want to count the number of "integer points" inside this curve, denoted by $N$. (By integer point, I mean a point with integer abscissa and ordinate.)

Now let $M$ be an integer large enough, and

$$F(x) = \sum_{k,l=-M}^M \frac{1}{x-(k+l\cdot\mathrm{i})}$$

One can easily check that

$$2\pi\mathrm{i}\cdot N = \int_{\gamma} F(z) \mathrm{d}z$$

where $\gamma(t)=x(t)+y(t)\cdot\mathrm{i}$.

Is this relation considered useful? If so, where can I find some references? If not, (mainly) why is that?

Comment: Isn't there a $2\pi\mathrm i$ factor missing? [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a factor $2 \pi i$?

Comment: thanks the two comments, fixed.

Comment: The overall idea is common, and variants of it are used all the time. I'm not sure of any applications where it is useful for counting integer points per se, but that is clearly just a limitation of my knowledge, But for a single point, it widely used as the definition of winding number (dropping "simple" from the conditions on the curve).